# XML-RPC to connect confluence in JAVA

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I have to use XML-RPC to upload a picture to confluence in JAVA.

JAVA CODE

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import helma.xmlrpc.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {

    // The location of our server.
    private final static String server_url =
        "http://confluence.xyz.com:8080/rpc/xmlrpc";

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {

            // Create an object to represent our server.
            XmlRpcClient server = new XmlRpcClient(server_url);

            Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>();
            params.add("username");
            params.add("pass");

            String token = (String) server.execute("confluence2.login", params );
            System.out.println(token);
        }
         catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaClient: " + exception.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error

```
JavaClient: java.io.IOException: SAX driver not found: org.apache.xerces.parsers.S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put additional [xercesImpl-2.2.1.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.2.1/xercesImpl-2.2.1.jar) for this. If you were using [maven](http://maven.apache.org) ,you can just simply add [xercesImpl maven dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.2.1) as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps!