# Java XML RPC getting Time Out Exception

Tags: java, xml-rpc

Need help to get response from server using java library helma.xmlrpc, i have read and try code in this link : [XML-RPC to connect confluence in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558235/xml-rpc-to-connect-confluence-in-java), this is the code that i've tried :

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import helma.xmlrpc.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RPC_appache {

    // The location of our server.
    private final static String server_url ="http://11.111.22.213:6789";
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            // Create an object to represent our server.
            XmlRpcClient server = new XmlRpcClient(server_url);
            Vector<Object> params = new Vector<Object>();
            params.add("username");
            params.add("pass");
            params.add("username");
            params.add("pass");
            String token = (String) server.execute("topUpInquiry", params );
            System.out.println(token);
        }
         catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("JavaClient: " + exception.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error :

> java.io.IOException: Connection timed out: connect    at
>   helma.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$Worker.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:135)   at
>   helma.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:67)   at
>   id.my.berkah.dmt.H2HRPC.RPC_appache.main(RPC_appache.java:31)
>   JavaClient: java.io.IOException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Your code looking for the wrong url, means may be `ip` and `port` are wrong.

Comment: thanx that's right, my url is incorrect.,.but how to set my xml version that i posted  to <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>